# ex command line for delete frome specific line to specific line in list.txt bash script

Tags: linux, vim, nano, ex

I have a `list.txt` file with a couple of lines like:

```
this line 1
this line 2
this line 3
this line 4
this line 5
this line 6
```

I want to delete from line 1 to line 2 with the `ex` command without using vim editor, I want use the `ex` command if that is possible

I just know how to delete specific word like break from the list:

```
$ ex +g/^"break"$/d -cwq list.txt
```

Comment: In Vim, do `:help :d` and `:help :range`.

Answer (score 1):

Below the command which displays the requested transformations.

```
$  ex list.txt +'1,2d' +'g/^break$/d' +'%s/this//g' +'wq'
```

Arguments of the given **ex** command:

> From line number (1) until (,) linenumber (2) inclusive, delete (d) line:

```
+'1,2d'
```

- Delete a specific line.
  For all line from beginning-to-the-end-of-file (g) match on starting line (^) with text (break) followed directly with end of line ($), do delete (d)

```
+'g/^break$/d'
```

- For all lines (%) subsitute (s) matching (/) something (this) (/) [with nothing] (/) also if multiple times one a line (g)

```
+'%s/this//g'
```

- Combined with the ex commands to write and quit:

```
 +'wq'
```

INPUT: list.txt

```
this line 1
this line 2
this line 3
this line 4
break
this line 5
this line 6
```

RESULTING OUTPUT: list.txt

```
 line 3
 line 4
 line 5
 line 6
```

Good luck